# C++ Inheritance, retrieving children's data members

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

I am trying to do this:

```
class Parameter
{
public:
    Parameter(){};
    ~Parameter(){};
};

class Address : public Parameter
{
public:
Address(uint16_t val) : value(val){};
Address(const Address& b) : value(b.value){};
~Address(){};
private:
uint16_t value;
};

class Constant : public Parameter
{
public:
Constant(int val) : value(val){};
Constant(const Constant& b) : value(b.value){};
~Constant(){};
private:
    int value;
};
```

How can I add set and get methods for the parent class Parameter so that when I create a Constant or Address object, I can use the parent methods to set and get the variable value?

Comment: declare it as protected in Parameter.

Comment: How would the parent be able to set the data when it does not have the data itself? What if someone had a parent class and called these functions? Have answered below in case I have misread things.

Comment: Looks like you want Parameter to be a template Parameter<T>, with a value member whose type is T. Address and Constant would be subclasses of Parameter<uint16_t> and Parameter<int>, respectively.

Comment: I am trying not to use templates because it complicates things later on in my application.

Comment: If you could give a bit more context in how you will be using this it would be easier to to give you a good answer. What is it you actually want to achieve and why?

Comment: Accessing the value in its native type is not something you will be able to use the base class to do.  Perhaps the base class will be useful for other things, like having virtual functions to serialize the value to a stream.

Comment: @user215833 (how that names comes up, mixing memory and desire): The member in the parent could be a void * to a dynamically allocated value, with casts in the children. Less barbarically, they could all get the same value type, but the value type would be a wrapper with multiple virtual cast operators or some equivalent. Each subclass has its own subclass of the wrapper, for its own actual data type. Parameter::get_value() returns the base parameter type. But that's hideously complicated. Reconsider using templates, if you want to avoid excess complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you meant, but here is a try:

```
template <typename T>
class Parameter
{
public:
    const T& getValue() { return value; }
protected:
    T value;
};

class Address : public Parameter<uint16_t>
{
public:
    Address() { value = 2154; }
    // ...
}

class Name : public Parameter<std::string>
{
public:
    Name() { value = "John Doe"; }
    // ...
}
```

Later you can do:

```
Address address;
Name name;
cout << name.getValue() << " lives at house no " << address.getValue();
// outputs "John Doe lives at house no 2154".
```

Comment: I am trying to avoid using templates because later on in my application I construct an object Instruction which takes a Parameter. I don't want to template that object as well.

Comment: How can this `Instruction` object read the parameter if it can't know what type it is? It isn't quite clear.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement it as a pure virtual function and over ride it in the below classes?

Comment: What would be the return type of the virtual function get_value() in Parameter?